# When is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Just as the title suggests, is there a way to find a equivlent condition when a subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ without having to find out all subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nontrivial subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ if and only if it is finitely generated.

Comment: An alternative way is to say that the image of the subgroup in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

If S isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ by isomorphism h then h(1)=q where q in $\mathbb{Q}$ , which implies $ h(\mathbb{Z}) = q\mathbb{Z}$ .
meaning that all subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $q\mathbb{Z}$ where $q\ne0$ in $\mathbb{Q}$